# python 物体検出　検出された物体の数を数えたい

Tags: python

for　(物体検出のループ)
・
・
・
cat_count = label_name.count('Cat')
print(cat_count)

物体を検出するたびにループされ
ラベルのついたバウンディングボックスが画像に現れる。

ループ内で猫を検出した数を出力したい。

猫が４匹映る画像の時、出力結果が
１（猫）
１（猫）
１（猫）
１（猫）
０（猫以外の物体）
といったようにループの数だけ別れてしまう。

出力結果を上記の場合、４にする方法を教えてください。(pyhton)

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！OpenCVを利用しているのでしょうか？記載されている情報が不足しているため、このままだと回答が付きにくいかと存じます。実際のソースコードや利用しているフレームワークを[編集]から追記すると、回答が得られやすくなりそうです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

単純に和をとりたいということであれば、ループの外に和を覚えておくための変数を用意すればよいです。

```
cat_all_count = 0
for ほにゃらら:
    ...
    cat_all_count += label_name.count('Cat')   # ひとつずつ足していく
print(cat_all_count)
```

それぞれの行がループの外か中かに注意してください。